# NancyFX Self Hosting with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, nancy

I am setting up a website using a static front end of HTML/Javascript that uses angularjs to call into a NancyFx web service that is self hosted inside a Window service.  I have a reverse proxy between the front end the Window service for the service call.  I have enabled IIS to use windows authentication.  My question is, what is the correct way to get the windows authentication information to be passed into the web service?

I have looked at other examples like the following:
http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/7a0174e5fd64/self-hosted-owin-nancyfx-service-with-windows-authentication-example.html
but when I access Thread.CurrentPrincipal the identity information is not filled out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/damianh/10086352) by damianh the property containing the user identity is different. In the gist they access the identity within a module using

```
var env = ((IDictionary<string, object>)Context.Items[Nancy.Owin.NancyOwinHost.RequestEnvironmentKey]);
var user = (IPrincipal)env["server.User"];
```

I have not tried it yet. Let us know if it works for you.